# trying to install Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

I'm trying to install Magento in a Hosting and when I access by the browser to **http://mydomain/magento/install.php** **but it redirects to** **http://mydomain/magento/index.php/install/** also appears a message like **"the page 'mydomain' doesn't work and it can't process that request now"**.

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Double check your web servers configuration, it sounds like PHP or the rewrite rules are attempting to use the redirect conditions.  Also what web server are you using?

Comment: it's on linux, Centos 6, and right now it has it's attributes like this: allow_url_fopen => OFF
auto_globals_jit => ON
default_charset => UTF-8
display_errors => OFF
error_reporting => E_ALL
file_uploads => on
max_execution_time => 30s 
max_input_time => 60s
max_input_vars => 1000 
memory_limit => 32 MB
post_max_size => 8 MB 
short_open_tag => ON
upload_max_filesize => 2 MB

Comment: And you are right @Boomer, I can't even get into the installation process

Answer (score -1):

you can click on check on checkbox the name with `skip base url validation`

and your installation works

and let me know if you still face issue

Comment: I believe he's referring to access the install pages at all, so no options are presented such as the skip base url validation.

Comment: @B00MER this error comes only when you trying to install magento other wise it will not come , I dont think so he is trying install any pages , and also how can you install pages ?? you can add pages , not installing the pages